# How to decrease Icon size in small screen in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome

How to decrease Icon size in small screens in bootstrap 4. I am working on a bootstrap my Goal is to decrease Icon size in the bootstrap in small screens. For example, right now I am in screen size
Mobile S-320 PX, here I need to decrease Icon size. Please help me to solve this issue. If I am not clear with my doubt, please put a comment.

This is Regform.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Regform.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSuitcase } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


class Regform extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid customcolor'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-12'>
                        <div className='Main'>
                            <div className='icon'>
                                <FontAwesomeIcon className='suitcasestyle fa-5x' icon={faSuitcase}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                            </div>
                            <div className='content'>
                                <h1>Job Application</h1>
                                <h3>Please complete the form below to apply for a position with us.</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className='Mainform'>
                                <form>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Regform
```

This is Regform.css

```
.Main {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.customcolor {
    background-color: #ff3f00
}


.suitcasestyle {
    color: white;
}

.content {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.content h1, h3 {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Font Awesome docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons)..

> "Icons inherit the font-size of their parent container which allow them to match any text you might use with them. With the following classes, we can increase or decrease the size of icons relative to that inherited font-size."

So just use @media query to responsively scale down the .icon font-size on mobile..

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .icon {
        font-size: .5rem;
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/jnkKSowuAX

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using .scss mixins that would be able to determine the screen size dynamically and deliver the appropriate icon based on screen size.

Basically scss would detect the screen size, viewport, whatever, and based on that serve a set of either css, fonts, whatever you want.